# How to use commands in bash script sequentialy?

Tags: bash, unix, bluetooth

I'm trying to make a script that turns my bluetooth on and connect to my phone, so what I need to do in the terminal is:

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth  # turn bluetooth on
bluetoothctl         # enter in an interactive interface to use bluetooth commands
connect <MAC_ADDRESS> # connect to my phone
```

What i tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
rfkill unblock bluetooth
bluetoothctl
connect <MAC_ADDRESS>
```

But the third line doesn't execute into the interactive interface of `bluetoothctl`, it executes when `bluetoothctl` stops running.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [the manual page](http://man.nicevoid.com/man/man1/bluetoothctl) of `bluetoothctl`:

> It can be automated by piping commands to standard input as the tool will exit when reading end-of-file (EOF).

So I would suggest:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
rfkill unblock bluetooth # same as before
echo "connect <MAC_ADDRESS>" | bluetoothctl # pipe your command into bluetoothctl's stdin
```

Comment: nice ! Be sure to read the manual page of the tools you're using in the future and try (sometimes they're hard, no pressure) to understand them before landing a question. You'll come out of it stronger :) Of course, if something is not clear, SO is the place to go. Can you mark this answer as accepted as well ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`#!/bin/bash
rfkill unblock bluetooth
bluetoothctl << EOF
connect <MAC_ADDRESS>
EOF`